# Call TestNG suite from maven1

Tags: java, maven, testng

i have a maven problem... i want to call a TestNG Suite (we are using testng 6.8.7) from maven 1 and i don't know how to do this (i have never worked with maven 1).

An update of maven is at the moment impossible, because it's a big environment full of jelly-, ant- and maven-scripts and we just want to start using TestNG without changing the enviroment (these scripts are used in different shell scripts, all should run as usual). Until now we used JUnit, but we are missing some features in JUnit so we want to switch to TestNG. I don't care if it is a dirty solution, we will update to maven 3 in future.

Here is a part of the maven.xml:

```
<project xmlns:ant="jelly:ant"
         xmlns:maven="jelly:maven"
         xmlns:j="jelly:core"
         xmlns:util="jelly:util"
         xmlns:i="jelly:interaction">

<goal name="releaseTest">
        <j:set var="testcase" value="com.test.release.InterfaceReleaseTestingSuite"/>
        <attainGoal name="test-single" />
        <attainGoal name="createTestReport" />
    </goal>
```

This is the current solution how we call a JUnit-Testing Suite.

The only thing i have found which comes close to an solution is this but i don't understand how to use the plugin: http://testng.org/doc/maven.html (scroll to the maven 1 section)

Any idea?

Thanks a lot. kr

Comment: Well I'm sorry to say it will come down to something like this: http://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/using/developing-plugins.html .

Comment: Omg... i didn't want to hear this. But it's a good hint... i could try to get maven-testng-plugin 1.2 running... or do you think that this old plugin cannot start a present testng suite for testng 6.8.7?

Comment: You don't need any special plugin to run testng tests. Just simply use maven-surefire-plugin and the approriate dependency to testng that's it...And start using Maven 3.X....Maven1 is dead very long and [Maven 2 is EoL](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html)